# Quick question regarding coordinate geometry

Tags: coordinate-systems

Note: My exam is in about 1 hour and i just realized that i have a unsolved paper, this is one of the questions that i wasn't able to answer from it. I would highly appreciate it if a full explanation is provided, thanks a lot in advance.

Show that the points A(3,4), B(-4,3), and C(5,0) lie on the circle having center O.

Comment: Are you given a radius? Do you know how to describe a circle analitically? Do you really mean circle or just circumference?

Comment: Radius isnt given, but i figured it out with distance formula. I have no idea what the second question means and the third, well the question says that i need to prove the given points lie on the circle/its circumference. Problem is, idk how i can prove that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The center of the circle is the origin $(0,0).\,$ One of the points given is $(5, 0).\,$ Hence it is located at a distance of $\sqrt{5^2 + 0^2} = \sqrt{25} = 5$ from the origin. So the circle centered at the origin, with the radius of $5$ interesects $(5,0)$. Now, if all points lie on the same circle, they will will satisfy the equation of the circle centered at the origin whose radius is $\,5$:

$$x^2 + y^2 = 5^2 = 25$$

Check whether the coordinates of your other two points satisfy this equation. If so, they all lie on that circle.

$$\;\;\;(3, 4): \;\;3^2 + 4^2 = 9 + 16 = 25 = 5^2 \quad\qquad \checkmark$$

$$\;\;(-4, 3):\quad(-4)^2 + 3^2 = 16 + 9 = 25 = 5^2\quad \checkmark$$

Hence all points lie on the same circle of radius $5$, centered at the origin.

---

ADDED: In general, if you have a point defined as the center of the circle $(x_c, y_c)$, and you have many points to test, this approach works nicely:

Pick one point other than the center of the circle, $(x_1, y_1)$ and compute it's distance from the center point, i.e. compute the radius $r$ of the circle centered at $(x_c, y_c)$ and intersecting $(x_1, y_1)$: $$r = \sqrt{(x_1 - x_c)^2 + (y_1 - y_c)^2}\tag{radius}$$

Then, you can write the equation of the circle centered at $(x_c, y_c)$ with radius $r$ as follows:

$$ (x - x_c)^2 + (y - y_c)^2 = r^2\tag{equation of circle}$$

Now you're set to determine whether all the points you need to test lie on the circle simply by checking whether they satisfy the equation of the circle.

Comment: To show all points lie on the same circle, the equation of which is posted above, then they will each make the equation true. That's all you need to do to show (prove) they like on the same circle.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i wanted to confirm its the radius being same as i never actually saw this kind of a question and dont wanna get something wrong in the exams.

Comment: Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you calculate the radius as the distance between all the points and the origin, and if the distance is the same then they are all radius of the circle.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Calculate the distance of each of your three points from $(0,0)$.

**Added:** The distance between $(a,b)$ and $(p,q)$ is equal to
$$\sqrt{(a-p)^2+(b-q)^2}.$$
This is a formula that you are probably expected to remember for your test.

Take $(p,q)=(0,0)$. We get the simpler expression
$$\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$
for the distance from $(a,b)$ to the origin. That is also an immediate consequence of the Pythagorean Theorem.

Take $(a,b)=(3,4)$. The distance from $(3,4)$ to the origin is $\sqrt{3^2+4^2}$. This is $5$.

Similarly, the distance from $(-4,3)$ to the origin turns out to be $5$. Also, more simply, the distance from $(5,0)$ to the origin is $5$.

So all our points are at distance $5$ from the origin.

The circle of radius $5$ with centre the origin consists of all points at distance $5$ from the origin.

So all our points are on that circle.

**Remark:** I suggest you graph these points carefully. The geometry will become clear.

Comment: Please provide the full steps, i already calculated the distances using the distance formula but i have no idea how to actually prove this, i didnt even study anything about circles and coordinate geometry at all. :(

Comment: I'm afraid that if you ask this question *after* checking Andre's hint you may not be prepared for an exam on this...

Comment: well technically i am not prepared, most of the material coming in the exams arent even seen by us. Although out of the sample papers that i solved so far, i do have a 96 percent accuracy D: